# What does Win32_Printer class PrinterStatus "6 (0x6) Stopped printing" mean?

Tags: winapi, printing

See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Search for "PrinterStatus"

What does "Stopped printing" mean?  Did the print job finish?  Or is this an "error" state?

Comment: It means whatever the printer driver says it means, they are not created equal.  But it is not likely to be a finished job, that would normally be "idle".  Fairly safe to assume that it is a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, that's not determined by the printer driver since the driver would have already rendered the job and sent it on to the spooler for processing by the port monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: the printer has stopped printing for some reason.  The most likely reason would be a paper jam, out of paper, or similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's what I figured, but wasn't entirely sure.